# Бесконечный цикл while при вызове с БД

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть БД, хочу вывести от туда значения через цикл while, но при открытии кода в браузере, начинается бесконечная прокрутка этого цикла. Помогите с решением.
PHP код:

```
$queryConnEntity = "SELECT * FROM `entity`";
$sqlConnEntity = mysqli_query($link, $queryConnEntity);

$resultEntityAside = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlConnEntity);

while( $resultEntityAside ) {
   echo($resultEntityAside['entity']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в понимании, как работает `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`. Эта функция работает как генератор. Каждый новый вызов функции `mysqli_fetch_assoc` возвращает ассоциативный массив новой строки или `false` в случае, когда строки закончились или отсутствуют вообще.

В Вашем случае, постоянно возвращало первую строку.

```
$queryConnEntity = "SELECT * FROM `entity`";
$sqlConnEntity = mysqli_query($link, $queryConnEntity);


while( $resultEntityAside = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlConnEntity)) {
   echo($resultEntityAside['entity']);
}
```